# What is wrong with my defintion of the function prompt_int?

Tags: python, random

I have been trying to program a maths quiz that both works and is as efficient as possible. Looking over my code I saw I had a lot of integer inputs and that lead to me having the program to ask the question/exit the system if the criteria isn't met, so to help me I thought that it would be useful to create a new function. Here is my attempt:

```
def prompt_int(prompt=''):
    while True:
        if status == prompt_int(prompt=''):
            val = input(prompt)
            if val in (1,2):
                return int(val)
                return true
        elif status != prompt_int(prompt=''):
            val = input(prompt)
            if val in (1,2,3):
                return int(val)
                return true
        else:
            print("Not a valid number, please try again")
```

However, when I try to implement this function around my code it doesn't work properly as it says that status isn't defined however, when I do define status it goes into a recursion loop. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my original code before i try to implement this function:

```
import sys
import random
def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            sys.exit("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected) please try again")
status = input("Are you a teacher or student? Press 1 if you are a student or 2 if you are a teacher")# Im tring to apply the new function here and other places that require integer inputs
if status == "1":
    score=0
    name=input("What is your name?")
    print ("Alright",name,"welcome to your maths quiz."
            "Remember to round all answer to 5 decimal places.")
    level_of_difficulty = int(input(("What level of difficulty are you working at?\n"
                                 "Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate "
                                    "or 3 for high\n")))
    if level_of_difficulty not in (1,2,3):
        sys.exit("That is not a valid level of difficulty, please try again")
    if level_of_difficulty == 3:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    else:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    for question_num in range(1, 11):
        if level_of_difficulty == 1:
            number_1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
            number_2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
        else:
            number_1 = random.randrange(1, 20)
            number_2 = random.randrange(1, 20)
        operation = random.choice(ops)
        maths = round(eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2)),5)
        print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
        print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)
        answer = float(input("What is your answer: "))
        if answer == maths:
            print("Correct")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)
    if score >5:
        print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
    else:
        print("Unfortunately you only scored",score,"out of 10. Better luck next time")
    class_number = input("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")
    while class_number not in ("1","2","3"):
        print("That is not a valid class, unfortunately your score cannot be saved, please try again")
        class_number = input("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")
    else:
        filename = (class_number + "txt")
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty))
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f = open(filename, "r")
            lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
            f.close()
            lines.sort()
        if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
            for line in lines:
                print (line)
        else:
            sys.exit("Thanks for taking part in the quiz, your teacher should discuss your score with you later")
if status == "2":
    class_number = input("Which classes scores would you like to see? Press 1 for class 1, 2 for class 2 or 3 for class 3")
    if class_number not in (1,2,3):
        sys.exit("That is not a valid class")
    filename = (class_number + "txt")
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        f.close()
        lines.sort()
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
```

Comment: Why line 6 and 7? The second return will never execute! No?

Comment: What could I replace it with?

Comment: With "if status == prompt_int(prompt=''):" you cycle (recursive) on the function prompt_int!!

Comment: You could replace by "return int(val), true"!

Comment: That still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Yes, of course: you try: "if val in (1,2):" but val is a string! Look at my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a part:

```
def prompt_int(prompt=""):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if val in ("1", "2"):
            return int(val), True
```

Will ask again and again. And return when the user enter "1" or "2"!
But better: "if val in "12":

Comment: Is there some sort of continue function I could use

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I tried to use this new definition but instead of carrying on when I input 1 or 2 the program just stops what could I do to make sure it continues as it should

Comment: With my response: you "have" to answer "1" or "2"… Else it ask again. But you can add a "q" for not having to respond "1" or "2"! You can either test "123456789q", no? And if you give a right answer, the function return a tuple (val, True)

Comment: Yes but when I answer 1 or 2 the program just stops for some reason.

Comment: Have you try in Python shell?

Comment: Arf! IDLE is part of Python and it lets you try easily (to "see" what append).

Comment: Ho no! It's just because I was surprise! (I often use this shell to try and see what's append, and it give you help… So for me python shell is very very useful!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def prompt_int(prompt=""):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if val.isdigit():
            return int(val)
```

Hi if you dont want to have valid values send to your you could change your code as the function above.

But you could also change it to do the system exits:

```
def prompt_int(prompt="", authorized=()):
    while True:
        val = raw_input(prompt)
        if val.isdigit():
            if int(val) in authorized:
                return int(val)
            else:
                sys.exit("Bla bla bla too bad")
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the system is meant to continue but if I enter an authorized number the program just stops

Comment: That means you just have to use the normal (first) one, which just make sure that you get an Int.

Comment: "doesn't work properly" is a totally useless description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def prompt_int(prompt=''):
    while True:
        if status == prompt_int(prompt=''):
```

This line will look for the name "status" in the global namespace (module's namespace), and raise a NameError if there's no global variable named 'status'.
If there's one, it will then recursively calls `prompt_int` without any possible termination, resulting theoretically in an endless recursion, but practically (in CPython at least) in a `RuntimeError` when it will hit the maximum recursion depth.

There are also quite a few other things that won't work as you expect:

```
        val = input(prompt)
        if val in (1,2):
```

In Python 3.x, `val` will be a string, so it will never compare equal to an `int`. In Python 2.x, `input()` is a shortcut for `eval(raw_input())`, which might return an `int`, but is also a huge security flaw since it unconditionnally execute untrusted code.

```
            return int(val)
            return true
```

The second `return` statement will never be executed, obviously, since the function will exit at the first one.

A simpler implementation might look like this:

```
# rebinds raw_input to input for python < 3
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    input = raw_input

def prompt_int(prompt='', choices=None):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)

        try:
            val = int(val)
            if choices and val not in choices:
                raise ValueError("{} is not in {}".format(val, choices))
            return val
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(
                    "Not a valid number ({}), please try again".format(e)
                    )
```

While we're at it, there's room for improvement in other parts of your code. Let's start with this:

```
def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            sys.exit("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected) please try again")
```

First point: your naming is not consistent. If your other function is named `prompt_int`, this one should be named `prompt_bool`. Also, you have one function (prompt_int) looping forever and the other one exiting the whole program on invalid input, which is another inconsistency. If you want to allow the user to exit on any prompt, provide an explicit option for it, ie:

```
def prompt_bool(prompt, quit='Q'):
    prompt += " (hit '{}' to exit) : ".format(quit)
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).strip().upper()
        if val == quit:
            sys.exit("Goodbye")
        elif val == 'yes':
          return True
        elif val == 'no':
          return False
        else:
            print "Invalid input '{}', please try again".format(val)
```

Of course you then want to provide the same option in `prompt_int()`, which leads to a more generic function:

```
def get_input_or_quit(prompt, quit="Q"):
    prompt += " (hit '{}' to exit) : ".format(quit)
    val = input(prompt).strip()
    if val.upper() == quit:
        sys.exit("Goodbye")
    return val

def prompt_bool(prompt):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
          return True
        elif val == 'no':
          return False
        else:
            print "Invalid input '{}', please try again".format(val)
```

And of course you also replace the call to `input` by a call to `get_input_or_quit` in `prompt_int`.

We could go on for long - splitting all your code in distinct, self-contained function, writing a "main()" function to drive them (instead of having the "main" part at the top level), and obviously using the `operator` module instead of `eval()`.

Comment: When I used this it prints "Not a valid number (argument of type 'float' is not iterable), please try again" whenever i press 1 or 2 or any number

Comment: @qwertyuiop `prompt_int`s "choices" argument must be a list or tuple of ints, not a float.

Comment: @ bruno desthuillers the choices argument is a list of ints